# How to get the Mailaddress by the Name of an exchange user

Tags: powershell, exchange-server, powershell-cmdlet

I try to run a Script that will give mal participants of a mail-distributiongroup and their mailaddresses. For the participants it works quite well, while for the owners it doesent work, because im only able to get tehir displayname as String. Is there a way to get the Mailaddress by the Name of an exchange user.

```
# Get all distribution groups
$groups = Get-DistributionGroup -ResultSize Unlimited 

# Loop through each group
foreach ($group in $groups) {

# Get the group's name and email address
$groupName = $group.Name
$groupEmail = $group.PrimarySmtpAddress

# Get the list of owners
$owners = $group.ManagedBy 

# Get the list of participants
$participants = Get-DistributionGroupMember $group | Select-Object - 
ExpandProperty PrimarySmtpAddress

#do smth with it
}
```

The term $Managed by only gives me the displayname of the Owners as String.
I already tried to access the mailaddress by iterating through the list of owners:

```
foreach ($owner in $owners) {
$ownerAddress = Get-Mailbox -Filter "displayName -eq '$owner'"
}
```

It returns nothing, as well with the -Anr Flag or -Credentails.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Hi MirrahOH you can get the info from manager whit this line**

```
# Get the list of owners
$owners = $group.ManagedBy 
    #manager informations 
    Get-ADUser -Identity $owners.DistinguishedName -Properties mail
# Get the list of participants
```

Comment: It seems to be the only workaround, even tho I dont understandt why I cant accsess it via exchange directly. 
Thank you very much.

Comment: in the managedby properties is not a mail properties that is the problem  we cannot read direct from that. here are the propertis 
OrgHierarchyToIgnore  ;
IsDeleted             ;
Rdn                   ;
Parent                ;
Depth                 ;
DistinguishedName     ;
IsRelativeDn          ;
DomainId              ;
PartitionGuid         ;
PartitionFQDN         ;
ObjectGuid            ;
Name                  ;